# WCF Web Service, cross-domain example

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, iis

Can anyone point me to a good/simple example of creating a WCF web-service sitting on one website, followed with a simple example consuming that WCF web-service on another website?

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751514.aspx has some good examples for using WCF.

Consuming WCF from another site should be failrly straight forward, just don't forget  to use a clientaccesspolicy.xml file.

Comment: I've created a WCF service and now it wants me to use Svcutil.exe to generate (I guess) the class for my client.. does one always have to use Svcutil.exe?

Comment: No. You can use "Add Service Reference", which is pretty much the same thing.

Comment: how does one *use* a clientaccesspolicy.xml file?  I see them mentioned here and there but have no idea where to get one or how to create my own.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for WCF techniques and examples in general, I would highly recommend you visit [IDesign's web site](http://www.idesign.net).  The company was founded by Juval Lowy, one of the preeminent experts on WCF.  The downloads are free to access and use; you just have to provide your email address.